# Chrome расширение: запросы к серверу

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

Есть расширение, там присутствует обычный `AJAX-запрос`(на чистом `JS`) к серверу.

**Вопрос:** почему запрос отправляется? Отправляется, несмотря на то, что у меня на сервере НЕ стоит заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

А если, запустить этот файл локально, то выдает ошибку:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load {url}. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

API расширений специально было спроектировано с учетом данной возможности. XHR запросы из расширений не имеют ограничений по `same origin policy`.

Подробнее об этом можно почитать в английском документации к Chrome Extensions: [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr)

Достаточно лишь правильно указать `permissions` в manifest.json.